# How to search C++Builder component properties

Tags: c++builder, vcl

Using C++Builder 10.3 VCL for Windows. I am using a `TImageList` and I need to search all of my project's components to identify which components use that `TImageList` in their `Images` property. When I do a search, it shows no results, apparently it is only searching the code. How can I search all the components properties to look for the `TImageList`?

Comment: There is no such search option implemented natively in the IDE at design-time. You would need to write (or find) a custom ToolsAPI expert to do it. Otherwise, you can do it manually in your code at runtime using RTTI. Why do you need to find all references to your `ImageList`? What are you going to do with those results?

Comment: I am switching to VirtualImageList and need to replace all the old component Property references to ImageList, before I delete the old ImageList. I would like to see a list of all the references to ImageList so I can make sure I replace them all.

Comment: For something like that, I would just open all of the DFMs in the IDE, right click and "View as Text", do a plain search+replace on the `TImageList`'s name, then right-click and "View as Form".

Comment: Viewing DFM as text allowed me to solve the problem. Thanks.